# Shell Script to move folders containing a specific word

Tags: shell, scripting, rename

I'm searching for an simple shell script to `mv` all folders in `/var/www/uploads/` that containing **Math** or **Physics** in the name to `/mnt/Backup/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this SO Post: [use xargs to mv the “find” directory into another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899794/1195001)
i would use something like :

```
 find /var/www/uploads/ -type d  \( -name '*Physics*' -o -name '*Math*' \) \
    -exec mv -t /mnt/Backup/ {} +
```

This will find any directory at any depth in your `/var/www/uploads` folder and move it to the backup dir.
If you  want to limit the search to the first level you can add to find the option `-maxdepth 1`

```
find /var/www/uploads/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  \( -name '*Physics*' -o -name '*Math*' \) \  
-exec mv -t /mnt/Backup/ {} +
```

And if you want to have a case insensitive search you can use the argument `-iname` instead of `-name` so it looks like :

```
 find /var/www/uploads/ -type d  \( -iname '*Physics*' -o -iname '*Math*' \) \
   -exec mv -t /mnt/Backup/ {} +
```

**Note:**
 this will only work with recent versions of GNU or FreeBSD `find` and `mv` (`-iname`, `-maxdepth` and `-t` are not standard).

I also use `\` to add jumpline in the command line and make it more readable.

#### Note 2:

If you want have a nice understanding of the command you can try [this ExplainShell link](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20/var/www/uploads/%20-maxdepth%201%20-type%20d%20%20%5C%28%20-name%20%27*Physics*%27%20-o%20-name%20%27*Math*%27%20%5C%29%20%5C%20%20%20-exec%20mv%20-t%20/mnt/Backup/%20%7B%7D%20%2b)

Comment: @stephaneChazelas why the edit if it's what I want to write ?

Comment: Yours didn't work as you forgot the `-print0`. Rather than adding the non-standard `-print0`, I prefered to fix it by using the standard syntax instead.

Comment: Works very well. Thank you for sharing this! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
# replace echo with mv when output OK
echo /var/www/uploads/*@(Math|Physics)* /mnt/Backup/
```

Comment: could you explain what it does

Comment: @Kiwy It does exactly what the OP wants, doesn't it? And that's more or less the best description of what is happening. You may search in `man bash` for "pattern-list".

Comment: I was more curious about the  `shopt -s extglob` option

Comment: @Kiwy I guess `extglob` is disabled by default. But (as you would have found at exactly that place in the man page) it is needed to make the `@()` work (which is called extended globbing).

Comment: Thanks for the update, I didn't know this option.

Comment: Note that that is ksh extended globbing syntax, so the above will work in `ksh` (after removing the `shopt`), and in `zsh`, you need `setopt kshglob`. With `zsh`'s extended globs (`setopt extended_globs`), the syntax is just `*(Math|Physics)*`. `zsh` also has globbing qualifiers that allow you to select directories only (`*(Math|Physics)*(/)`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Just removing `echo` would not have led to the intended result...

Comment: Yes sorry, wrong edit. Might be better with `echo mv ...` and then remove the `echo` though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the unix command `find`, with the option `-d` to search for directories only, and tell it to execute the command to move the directory to /mnt/Backup. Instead of using a regexp to do it in one step, I'd simply run the command twice, like this:

```
find /var/www/uploads -type d -name "*Math*" -exec mv {} /mnt/Backup/ \;
find /var/www/uploads -type d -name "*Physics*" -exec mv {} /mnt/Backup/ \;
```

If you want to do the same thing for a large number of directory names, so that you don't want to have to repeat names, you can use a variable instead:

```
for name in Math Physics; do find /var/www/uploads -d -name "*${name}*" -exec mv {} /mnt/Backup/ \;
```